# Deactivate a spinbox in Qt Designer

Tags: python, qt-designer, qspinbox, qradiobutton

Is it possible to deactivate a spinbox if a radiobutton is chosen? I've tried several things, but either the spinbox is deactived all the time or it wont deactivate at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what you have been doing (perhaps you should mention what exactly instead of writing "tried several things" ;)) but yes, you can. In the slot-signal view select the radiobutton and drag a connection to the spinbox. For the signal emitted by the radiobutton choose `toggled(bool)`. For the slot in the spinbox you need to check the `Show signals and slots inherited from QWidget` first (at the bottom of the connection dialog) in order to display all possible slots and then select either `setDisabled(bool)` or `setEnabled(bool)`.